# DateTime.ParseExact not working at all, why?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date-format, datetime-parsing

I am attempting to parse the following `String` into a `DateTime` object in c#:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20101108 230125", "yyyyMMdd hhmmss", null)
```

although the value looks correct the `ParseExact` method just keeps giving me the following:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Can anybody tell me why and how I can parse the above string without having to do it the manual way? Isn't `ParseExact` supposed to be for this kind of occasion?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You got the format for hours wrong, should be uppercase:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20101108 230125","yyyyMMdd HHmmss", null)
```

Lowercase `hh` specifies that the time uses a 12-hour clock (with AM/PM). Uppercase `HH` is a 24 hour clock time.

For detailed info, check the [documentation of custom DateTime format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: Why does this cause an exception? Personally I would expect hh to convert 23 into 11 rather than throw an exception. Is it ParseExact that causes it?

Comment: @Marcus: `ParseExact` will do what it says; parse the the string using the *exact* format specified. Since `hh` tells it to expect a 12-hour clock time value in that position, `23` clearly falls outside of the range of acceptable values. It parses the exact string, no conversions are made. So yes, the exception is thrown by the `ParseExact` method.

Comment: Cheers for the extended explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20101108 230125", "yyyyMMdd HHmmss", null)
```

The "hh" is for 12 hour time and "HH" for 24 hour.